# Using Eclipse instead of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

In the year 2020, is it still possible to use Eclipse for Android app development?

If so, what are the current steps for setting up such an environment?

Comment: It is no longer supported: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html

Comment: As the other commenter pointed out, the reality is that a complex development environment needs support, and the Eclipse Android suite is no longer supported.